# Ошибка при распаковке GZIP

Tags: php

Вылазит ошибка при распаковке функцией `gzinflate()`,подскажите в чем проблема!

```
$url = "http://capitalcity.combats.com/logs.pl?log=1392725194.42632";
$log = file_get_contents($url);

echo gzinflate($log);

Warning: gzinflate() [function.gzinflate]: data error in C:\xampp\htdocs\analyzer\index.php on line 6
```

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.zlib-decode.php

Comment: Спасибо большое,то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Уже взял ради интереса отправил заголовок `header("Content-Encoding: gzip");` Страница отображается корректно,но если пользуюсь функцией `strpos` пытаюсь найти позицию искомого текста то ничего не происходит.Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема,хочу разобраться в этом теме!